# When Oracle constraint is violated, set default? How do I do this?

Tags: sql, oracle, default, create-table

I'm having some issues with setting a default value in a Oracle database.

I want to set the default value for my region to NW: `region CHAR(2) DEFAULT ('NW'),`

I also have a reference check to make sure all values in region are 2 characters:
  `CONSTRAINT check_region CHECK (region IN ('N', 'NW', 'NE', 'S', 'SE', 'SW', 'W', 'E')));`

However, I'm getting this error when I'm inserting data which does not fit my constraint. I have a row of data which has `'NULL'` for a value so it should not be inserted ... but it should default to the default value of NW ... right?

```
Error starting at line : 16 in command -
INSERT into acctmanager
 (amid, amfirst, amlast, amedate, amsal, amcomm, region) VALUES ('L500','MANDY','LOPEZ','01-OCT-09', 47000, 1500, 'NULL')
Error report -
ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS.CHECK_REGION) violated
```

I understand the error should pop up ... but should the value not default to what I have defined in my schema for `region` ? I've tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388778/insert-default-value-when-null-is-inserted) but I'm still getting the error with inserting.

Any suggestions?

Here is my entire create table statement:

```
DROP TABLE ACCTMANAGER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE acctmanager
(amid CHAR(4),
 amfirst VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,
 amlast VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,
 amedate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
 amsal NUMBER(8,2),
 amcomm NUMBER(7,2),
 region CHAR(4) DEFAULT ('NW'),
  CONSTRAINT PK_acctmanager PRIMARY KEY (amid),
  CONSTRAINT check_region CHECK (region IN ('N', 'NW', 'NE', 'S', 'SE', 'SW', 'W', 'E')));

INSERT into acctmanager
 (amid, amfirst, amlast, amedate, amsal, amcomm, region) VALUES ('T500','NICK','TAYLOR','05-SEP-09', 42000, 3500, 'NE');
INSERT into acctmanager
 (amid, amfirst, amlast, amedate, amsal, amcomm, region) VALUES ('L500','MANDY','LOPEZ','01-OCT-09', 47000, 1500, 'NULL');
INSERT into acctmanager
 (amid, amfirst, amlast, amedate, amsal, amcomm, region) VALUES ('J500','SAMMIE','JONES','DEFAULT' , 39500, 2000, 'NW');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
VALUES ('L500','MANDY','LOPEZ','01-OCT-09', 47000, 1500, 'NULL')
```

Not `'NULL'`, but `NULL` (without single quotes).

**[EDIT]**

Here's an example of a trigger:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id      number,
  3     region  varchar2(2) default 'NW'
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_test
  2    before insert or update on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.region not in ('N', 'NW', 'NE') then
  6       :new.region := 'NW';
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: if the REGION name is longer than VARCHAR2 (as that's how the column is declared, insert will fail regardless the trigger):

```
SQL> insert into test (id, region) values (1, 'what?');
insert into test (id, region) values (1, 'what?')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT"."TEST"."REGION" (actual: 5, maximum: 2)
```

A shorter (up to 2 characters) will be OK:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, region) values (1, 'xx');

1 row created.
```

Inserting NULL into region will, actually, insert the default value:

```
SQL> insert into test (id) values (2);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select * From test;

        ID RE
---------- --
         1 NW
         2 NW

SQL>
```

**[EDIT #2: the `DEFAULT` keyword]**

Yet another option is to use the DEFAULT keyword, such as

```
SQL> insert into test (id, region) values (3, default);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test where id = 3;

        ID RE
---------- --
         3 NW
```

*Thanks to Wernfried for the comment.*

Comment: I would agree if it was a `NULL` value, but it is being passed in as a `String`. Is there a way to default the incorrect `String` being provided?

Comment: You might try with a database trigger; I don't think that a declarative constraint is capable of doing that.

Comment: I edited my message, providing an example. Have a look.

Comment: It was a combination of the user I was logged in as `sys` and not having the trigger set up correctly. Thank you for the great answer :)

Comment: You're welcome; though, saying that you were connected to SYS - if so, don't do that - don't mess up with SYS nor SYSTEM, they are *special* and not to be used for everyday work. Instead, create your own user, grant it privileges and proceed with what you're doing. If you unintentionally do something wrong with SYS, you'll break the database.

Comment: You can also write `insert into test (id, region) values (2, DEFAULT);`

Comment: @Wernfried: hm, I'm *sure* that yesterday someone posted the same answer as your comment (about the DEFAULT keyword) but it *automagically* disappeared during the night. Must be the person who posted it, but I'm not sure why (s)he did that ... Anyway, thank you for the comment; I'll include it into my answer for completeness.

Comment: Yes, it was deleted by owner - in spite of a correct answer. You don't have sufficient reputation (10k) yet to see deleted posts.

Comment: @Wernfried: ah, I see - or, should I rather say, *don't see*  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select from dual` instead of the `values` keyword.  That brings `nvl` into play.

So, instead of this:

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
values
(value1, value2, etc)
```

do this:

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select nvl(field1, default value1)
, nvl(field2, default value2)
, etc
from dual
```

Comment: I've never seen `nvl` and it might help me answer this question. Thanks